# How to go to another Lua file Corona SDK?

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I am doing a little game, I would like to know how to go to another Lua file in Corona SDK.
First of all, I have a main.lua with the first level.

I am trying this, make a main.lua with the menu, and level.lua with the first level, but I do not know how to go from main.lua to level1.lua. I read that `dofile` function does not work in Corona SDK.

Answer (score 1):

use gotoScene function. or search storyboard for further explaination

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried with storyboard, but I can´t or I don´t know how to use. Can you help me with my code?

Comment: when you start the simulator click file new and then select the Multiscreen Application it will generate code with a storyboard with scene template

Comment: And where I put my function?

Comment: where exactly do you want the user change the scene ?

Comment: In function function eliminar9.

Comment: you haven't implemented the storyboard on your code we cannot go to another scene i think you code this in main.lua

Comment: I didn´t implement the storyboard because I don´t know where to put my for loop and my functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
   local storyboard = require "storyboard"

local options =
{
    effect = "slideLeft",
    time = 800,
    params = { var1 = "custom", myVar = "another" }
}

storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", options )
```

If 'scene1' is in a folder then :

```
 storyboard.gotoScene( "path.to.folder.scene1", options )
```

See:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/index.html